# Webstorm css autocompletion in partial views

Tags: css, webstorm, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars and my templating engine but when I am working in a partial view the css files referenced in the main layout view are not being populated in the autocomplete dropdown.

Is there a way to have project based css files so the files dont have to be included on each individual view?

The example I have is that I am using bootstrap and it is include on the main layout view. When I create an individual page view I no longer have the classes in bootstrap available in the dropdown when i start typing.

If I have

```
<button class="bt
```

the bootstrap classes .btn, .btn-default etc. do not show up

Comment: works for me - all CSS selectors defined in project .css files are suggested by completion. Do you have any embedded CSS (<style> tags) or links to .css files in your partial? There are some issues that may be related: [WEB-311](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-311), [WEB-11431](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11431), [WEB-2223](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2223)

Comment: @lena Thank you very much! As of right now in webstorm you can not have inline styles and also reference project css files. I never even thought that would be an issue. For the future just remove inline styles.